# シャンクス見参! why there is no が in that sentence?

Tags: particle-が

I was watching one piece and came across with the title `シャンクス見参!` without `が`. I want to google it by myself the answer but I am not sure the proper keyword so I ask about it here. would you tell me why there is no `が` in the title? if you have link reference about, I'd love to read it.

And what's the meaning of it? the subtitle translate it as `shanks appears`. is that correct? but I tried google translate and it gave me worse translation `Shanks kenzan`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Japanese often omits "助詞" (particles) from  sentences.

For example:

> 先生が言ってたよ！→ 先生、言ってたよ！
>
> このぬいぐるみが欲しい。→ このぬいぐるみ欲しい。

In your case:

> シャンクスが見参した！→ シャンクス、見参！
>
> シャ  ン  ク  ス  /  け  ん  ざ  ん
> sya  n  ku  su (4 morae) / ke  n  za  n (4 morae)

This tempo sounds good, natural and impressive, the first and second half having the same number of morae/syllables.

My English is not good.
Please edit somebody! Bye!

Comment: Thank you :) .my english is not good too, you are not alone.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because it's an old-fashioned set phrase using old grammar. (Incidentally, it should be が if you dare to use any).

Comment: oh so it should be "ga" not "ha". okay thank you. I edited the question and wait for more longer before accepting your answer :)

Comment: btw may I know the reason why we use ga there? thank you :)

Comment: When you say or report something that has just happened or been discovered which is not shared in the existing context, you use a sentence that lacks topic parts, in short, you don't use は. This kind of sentence is  called 現象文 or "sentence of neutral description".

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the omission of this が make a stronger impression on people and shorten a sentence. So it is often used in titles.

When I make シャンクス見参 a sentence, it become シャンクスが見参する(した) but it is a bit long as a title, so it become シャンクス見参 as less word as possible but not to change the meaning.

Other examples are ヒーロー登場, ジャックス参上, 首相辞任, 日本連勝 etc.

A dictionary said 見参 means 目上の人が目下の者に会ってやること or 参上して目上の人に対面すること.シャンクス見参 means probably "Shanks came to see".

Comment: "came to see" seems correct translation, given the episode is about shanks came to battle field to stop the war. is there any short translation of it? or `appears` is the best approach? "came to see" seems too long for one verb kanji.

Comment: I think the word "appear" seems to be good.

Comment: "Shanks is here!" とか "Here comes Shanks!" とかどうでしょう？